# ROracle error ORA-12592 when insert a lot of rows

Tags: r, roracle

When i use `dbWriteTable` for dataframe with millions rows sometimes get `ORA-12592` error.

With small dataframe - all works fine.

Is there way to customize `dbWriteTable` for commit every X rows? Or other way to minimaze error?

option bulk_write = 1000L change nothing

Version:

> ROracle_1.3-1
>
> DBI_1.0.0